# What are those numbers in PyCharm's debug window and can I hide them?

Tags: pycharm

In PyCharm's debug windows I see all the variables and their values. I was wondering what the numbers beside the variable names are and if (and how) I can hide them?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the [id of the object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id). There is, as far as I know, no way to turn them off.